# First Order Logic Question

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

$\forall x\ \forall y\ P(x,y) \to \forall x\ \forall y\ P(y,x)$

> Is this a tautology?
>
> Is there a set method that we can use to find whether a wff is a tautology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If with the term *tautology* you mean also a *valid* formula of first-order logic, the answer is : YES.

In general, we have that : $\forall x \forall y \varphi$ and $\forall y \forall x \varphi$ are *equivalent*.

Thus, $∀x∀y P(x,y) \to ∀x∀y P(y,x)$ is equivalent to $∀x∀y P(x,y) \to ∀y∀x P(y,x)$.

In addition, you can "rename" the bounded variable without chenging the "meaning" of a formula, and thus $∀y∀x P(y,x)$ is equivalent to : $∀x∀y P(x,y)$.

In conclusion, the initial formula is equivalent to :

> $∀x∀y P(x,y) \to ∀x∀y P(x,y)$,

which is *valid* (it is an *instance* of the *tautology* : $p \to p$).

---

You can prove it "formally" with a *Natural Deduction* derivation of :

> $\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \vdash \forall x \forall y P(y,x)$.

Comment: Is some sort of truth table technique available to us for finding if a wff is valid?

Comment: @saladi - No; you have to produce a *derivation* of the formula, i.e. to prove that $\vdash \varphi$; by *soundness*, this implies $\vDash \varphi$.

Comment: Since you began with "if by tautology you mean ...," let me fill in that, on the other hand, if by "tautology" you mean "valid for purely propositional reasons" (which is what I would ordinarily mean), then the answer is "no". (I expect though, that what you wrote is what the OP meant.)